# is there an API to get all of an Instagram business account's posts that include a particular hashtag?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I am trying to get media with an hashtag that is specific to a particular user. Instead, the api seems to provide all the public images with the hashtags that is not specific to the account.

This is the api to get media nodes using hashtag that I tried:

```
{hashtag-id}/recent_media?user_id={iguserId}&fields=id,media_type,comments_count,like_count,caption
```

This one returns the public images associated with that particular hashtag in addition to the account's media that I need. For example: 
I am requesting for images in a user's account that has #xxxx as hashtag. I am expecting the account's images alone containing xxxx tag. However, in the response I am receiving images from other accounts as well which has the same #xxxx hashtag. This api seems to work globally and I don't understand the use of 'user_id' parameter in the api.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this [API](https://instaloader.github.io/as-module.html). Very simple to use and you can get media from a hashtag and specify an account. This will help you get all of an Instagram business account's posts.

Python 3.x Implementation:

```
import instaloader

# Get instance

L = instaloader.Instaloader()

#Load the UserName

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, USERNAME)

#Read the profile posts and downloads those containing the hashtags

for i in profile.get_posts():
    if HASHTAG in i.caption_hashtags:
        L.download_post(i, target=DIRECTORY_NAME)
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort. However, I was looking for something inside the instagram graph API.

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you have tried. Try adding a  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added more details.